# Ugly 'post date' alignment on user profile when the date wraps into multiple lines

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

[image]

I think that the post date on user profiles looks messy: it sometimes looks right-aligned (as in the posts on October 2), and it sometimes ends up in a strange left-align (the dates which wrap into a new line). Can this be resized such that all dates show up in just one line, with everything right-aligned?

I observed this on Vivaldi 2.0 and Brave 0.24 for Windows 10, on the Physics profile page of [this user](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/8563/emilio-pisanty).

Answer (score 2):

Since the changes described in [Now live: A fully responsive profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370964/295232), this issue does not occur anymore:

[image]