# Question/Answer indicator on 'top posts' gets cropped when the question name is long

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

[image]

The little indicator which tells me whether the post is a question or an answer gets cropped on the right side when the question title wraps into two lines. This occurs whether or not the question/answer is accepted, and it happens on all communities, though that screenshot was taken on Physics.

I'm on Vivaldi 2.0 for windows 10.

Comment: Date column is also affected: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316458/339911

Comment: @alexolut I made a post about that yesterday: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316390/

Comment: In my mind that bug will be fixed automatically (i.e. no need to separate bug reports).

Comment: @alexolut That's probably right. I didn't ever consider the possibility that they're connected, so I made two separate posts, Also, I realized them at different times.