# Too much width for long post title in profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

When the post title is long enough then such string occupies too much space in profile page on the post section. For example in [this profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/196016/kendall-lister):

> [image: long title]

As you can see the “Q” icon is obscured by the post score indicator, and post date is wrapped to two lines.